# Sending email confirmation or using play store account to authenticate the user's account for my app?

Tags: java, android, email

I am developing an app in android and it needs to authenticate the user's email validity, but I am lost and don't have any clues on how to confirm if the user have a valid account...

Should I send a confirmation email to the user's email to confirm his validity? If yes how would I implement this?

Should I use a play store service to authenticate his account???

**Really I don't know!**

I am thinking of embedding or linking the user's playstore account into my app but I heard that it's a nut job, can you recommend an easier or a more convenient way to confirm the user's email?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling google sign in .

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

Here you will get the email address from the google account he is signed in his phone.

Comment: thanks man! I will get back to you in a month or so since I have no internet to test this at the moment, time is very limited cuz I'm using my friend's wifi and I'm about to go home! but really, appreciate it!